# firebase push-notification automatically clear previous notification

Tags: php, android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification

I have used FCM to set push notification in my android application and i am using FCM data not notification. i have added unique id to push message from my server but in my app when new notification is come it automatically clear my previous notification . 
**my push .php code**

```
class Push {
//notification title
private $title;

//notification message 
private $message;

//notification image url 
private $image;
private $notId;


//initializing values in this constructor
function __construct($title, $message, $image,$notId,$sound) {
     $this->title = $title;
     $this->message = $message; 
     $this->image = $image; 
      $this->notId = $notId; 
      $this->sound = $sound; 
}

//getting the push notification
public function getPush() {
    $res = array();
    $res['title'] = $this->title;
    $res['body'] = $this->message;
    $res['image'] = $this->image;
    $res['notId'] = $this->notId;
    $res['sound'] = $this->sound;
    return $res;
}
```

**firebase messaging service in my application**

```
lass myfirebasemessaging : FirebaseMessagingService() {
override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
    if (remoteMessage!!.data != null) {
        val title = remoteMessage.data!!.get("title")
        val body = remoteMessage.data!!.get("body")
        val tag = remoteMessage.data!!.get("notId")

        NotificationHelper.displayNotification(applicationContext, title!!, body!!, tag!!)
    }
}
```

**NotificationHelper**

```
 fun displayNotification(context: Context, title: String, body: String, notId: String) {
    val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            100,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
    )
    val mBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MainActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_waterlogo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText(body))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setDefaults(Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE)
    val mNotificationMgr = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
    val mp: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.notification)
    mp.start()
    mNotificationMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build())
}
```

same like i couldn't make any style to my notification. do i need to add anything additional in my fcm service and how can i use unique id in it for not clearing the previous message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace 1 with unique ID in this line.
 mNotificationMgr.notify(1, mBuilder.build())